# Simplification of boolean algebra from "not s and p" to "not s"

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

I am trying to learn more about "Rules of Inference" and their application, but one thing always confuses me, and that is simplification "not s and p" to "not s".

I have looked at some examples:

http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2101-10/lecturenotes/04InferenceRulesProofMethods.pdf page 18

http://www2.cs.siu.edu/~nojoumian/CS215/Files/Lec06_CS215.pdf page 16

And I simply dont understand how is it possible to reduce expression.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lnot s \not\equiv (\lnot s \land p),\;$ but it *is the case that* $\;\lnot s\;$ **follows from** $\;\lnot s \land p$.

"$\lnot s \land p$ is true" means

- $\lnot s$ is true, ***and*** $ p $ is true.

So it certainly *follows* that

- "$\lnot s$ is true,"

just as it *follows* that

- $p$ is true.

More simply put, we have

- $\lnot s$ AND $p$.

  - Therefore $\lnot s$.
  - Therefore $p$.

Comment: So when I have this type of assingments, where I need to rules of inference, I can presume that all of the expressions are true, and do assingment from there. Right? How do I know is it true or not?

Comment: @amWhy: Right up your alley! =1

Answer (score 1):

This simplification is not intended to be in the sense of rewriting a nicer-looking, equivalent statement. Instead, the simplification is a nicer-looking statement that logically follows from the first. Of course, if $\neg s\vee p$ is true, then $\neg s$ is true (and also $p$ is true, so $p$ would be another simplification in this sense).